# Spring Cloud Config - Vault and JDBC backend with JDBC creds in Vault

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am attempting to modify our current Spring Cloud Config server which has only a JDBC backend to include a Vault backend in order make the JDBC connection credentials secret.

**VAULT:**

```
 Listener 1: tcp (addr: "127.0.0.1:8400", cluster address: "127.0.0.1:8401", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")

C:\apps\HashiCorp>vault kv get secret/my-secrets
=============== Data ===============
Key                           Value
---                           -----
spring.datasource.password    yadayadayada
spring.datasource.username    cobar
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      allowOverride: true
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT prop_key, prop_value from CloudProperties where application=? and profile=? and label=?
          order: 2 
        #https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#vault-backend
        vault:
          scheme: http
          host: localhost
          port: 8400
          defaultKey: my-secrets
          order: 1
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/bootdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    #username: cobar
    #password: yadayadayada
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 60000
      maximum-pool-size: 5
  cloud:
    vault:
      scheme: http
      host: localhost
      port: 8400
      defaultKey: my-secrets
      token: root.RIJQjZ4jRZUS8mskzfCON88K
```

The spring.datasource username and password are not being retrieved from the vault.

```
2021-12-01 12:43:39.927  INFO 5992 --- [  restartedMain]: The following profiles are active: jdbc,vault
2021-12-01 12:43:46.123 ERROR 5992 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:a32
```

Answer (score 0):

Move properties from bootstrap to application context.

Call Vault endpoint to obtain secrets and use these to configure Datasource to JDBC backend.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static final String VAULT_URL_FRMT = "%s://%s:%s/v1/secret/%s";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(ConfigServerApplication.class);
        app.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter());
        app.addListeners(new WebServerPortFileWriter());
        app.run(args);
    }
    
    
    @Order(1)
    @Bean("restTemplate")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Configuration
    public class JdbcConfig {

        @Autowired
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

        @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            Secrets secrets = findSecrets();
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.url(secrets.getData().get("spring.datasource.url"));
            dataSourceBuilder.username(secrets.getData().get("spring.datasource.username"));
            dataSourceBuilder.password(secrets.getData().get("spring.datasource.password"));
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        }

        private Secrets findSecrets() {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.set("X-Vault-Token", env.getProperty("spring.cloud.vault.token"));
            HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
            String url = String.format(VAULT_URL_FRMT,
                env.getProperty("spring.cloud.vault.scheme"),
                env.getProperty("spring.cloud.vault.host"),
                env.getProperty("spring.cloud.vault.port"),
                env.getProperty("spring.cloud.vault.defaultKey")
            );
            return restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Secrets.class, 1).getBody();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Secrets implements Serializable {

    private String request_id;
    private String lease_id;
    private boolean renewable;
    private Duration lease_duration;
    private Map<String, String> data;

}
```

Now you have a Cloud Config with a JDBC backend you can keep the Database properties secret.